# ThreeJS difficulty properly merging a sphere with a box

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to attach a box to a sphere with ThreeJS when the two objects come into contact with each other. They should be attached at the point of their intersection (think Katamari Damacy). For some reason, with my code right now, when I merge the two objects by adding the box to the sphere's hierarchy, they do join, but the newly joined objects are not even close to each other. This is essentially my code:

```
var ball_geometry = new THREE.TetrahedronGeometry( 10, 2 );
var ball_material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {shading:THREE.FlatShading} );
player.mesh = new THREE.Mesh( ball_geometry, ball_material );

player.mesh.position.set(0,30,0);
scene.add( player.mesh );

var box_geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 20, 10, 10 );
var box_material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { shading:THREE.FlatShading});
box = new THREE.Mesh( box_geometry, box_material );

box.position.set(50,10,50);
scene.add( box);

player.mesh.add(box);
```

From my testing, it seemed that the initial position of my player.mesh played a part in how close the two objects are upon merging. For example, if the player.mesh spawns further away, then when it eventually collides with the box, the distance between the two objects is longer.

Any advice on how to tackle this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question: the position Vector3 of the box is only in relation to its parent. Thus the position I set for box.position ought to be with the consideration that (0,0,0) is its parent's position.